# How to post text to HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

Okay so what I am after for here is to check if a `checkbox` has been ticked, if it has, then I would like to add the text into a `<ul>` class named, let's say, "confirmed", so `<ul class="confirmed">`,

If it hasn't been checked, then I would add the text to a `<ul>` class named "unconfirmed". Now I have the php code that checks if the checkbox has been confirmed (seen below), but I don't know what to add inside the statements. This is where I need help/guidance.

PHP IF code (Check if checkbox is ticked):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["checkbox1"])){
    //write to <ul> class confirmed
    } else {
    //write to <ul> class unconfirmed
    } 


?>
```

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<body>

<div id="content">

    <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Is there football on Wednesday?</h1>
  <h2>Yes.</h2>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Confirmed Players</div>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
<!--this is where to result of the php code would go if the checkbox is checked-->
    Lorem Ipsor
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Unconfirmed Players</div>
  <li class="list-group-item">
<!--this is where to result of the php code would go if the checkbox is not checked-->
    Lorem Ipsor
  </li>
</div>

<!--form-->
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

</body>
```

Sorry if I seem to be confusing you, as I said, I'm not too well. Any help/guidance would be great!

Comment: Is this really about posting HTML "code"...because I get the impression it isn't really. Use proper terminology please so we can know what you're asking.

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, sorry, I've updated the title.

Comment: For me it seems that you're missing insert/select database part. So you can store confirmed people in database and just display them by getting results from database table.

Comment: Ok, well the answer is very obvious: nothing posts without a button to make it post. Your form just has a checkbox. Any basic HTML tutorial, even a bad one, will show you that you need a submit button.

Comment: You really need to go to an HTML tutorial instead of updating the question over and over to create a live tutorial. Your syntax for the submit button is wrong. A tutorial will tell you why.

Comment: The most common newbie confusion is to determine, what is running where and what is "posting" what to where. To start: PHP = server, HTML = client. If all is on your one machine, this is playing both roles, server and client, but in a straight order one after the other and not at the same time. And PHP is generating HTML, Apache is sending the HTML, your browser is rendering it, and "posting" is all the way back.

Comment: You can as well use AJAX to get the job done without refreshing the page, but that's just so you know the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so when you tick a checkbox it should return a value through the $_POST which is 1 or 0 on submit. You may modify your template like this:

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST['checkbox1']) {
    $class = 'confirmed';
    } 
    else {
    $class = 'unconfirmed';
    }

?>
<body>

<div id="content">

    <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Is there football on Wednesday?</h1>
  <h2>Yes.</h2>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Confirmed Players</div>

<ul class="list-group <?php echo $class; ?>">

  <li class="list-group-item">
    Lorem Ipsor
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Unconfirmed Players</div>

</div>

<!--form-->
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

To be sure you can always var_dump the $_POST to see what is coming through in it and modify your if statement to be more accurate, it should return 1 or 0 iirc.

Comment: Nice job parroting the syntax error `<input type="submit"></input>`.

Answer (score 1):

Without using AJAX you can try nesting php code like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
<?php

if (isset($_POST["checkbox1"])){
    //write to <ul> class confirmed
    }


?> 
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Unconfirmed Players</div>
  <li class="list-group-item">
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["checkbox1"])){
    //write to <ul> class unconfirmed
    }



?> 
  </li>
```

Comment: The problem is HTML related. The OP doesn't know basic HTML. No answer suggesting better PHP is a real answer to the question.

Comment: @developerwjk I do know basic HTML. It was a mistake that I forgot to include the full code above. As I have stated, I do not feel too good and my lack of concentration is to blame.